# Java: Creating an array of only duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I did a lot of searching on this subject, but I couldn't find anything usable for my problem: I'm making a simple memory game in Java based on an integer array. I want the array to contain only duplicate entries and no unique ones. Unfortunately most of the questions here are dealing with avoiding or removing duplicate entries, but what about enforcing them?

My code so far looks like this.

```
public Field[] getField(){
    Random r = new Random();
    int pool = 16;
    ArrayList<Integer> used = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int rand = r.nextInt(pool);
    System.out.println("First random: " + rand);

    for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        System.out.println("ITERATION " + i + " STARTED");
        while(used.contains(rand)){
            System.out.println(rand + " is used, recalculating...");
            rand = r.nextInt(pool);
            System.out.println("New random is " + rand);
        }

        fields[i] = new Field(rand);
        System.out.println(rand + " added in Field " + i);

        int tmp = r.nextInt(fields.length - 1);
        System.out.println("First tmp calculated: " + tmp);

        while(fields[tmp] != null && i <= fields.length / 2){
            tmp = r.nextInt(fields.length - 1);
            System.out.println("Field " + tmp + " is used, looking for another...");
        }

        fields[tmp] = new Field(rand);
        System.out.println(rand + " added in temp Field " + tmp);

        used.add(rand);
        System.out.println("ITERATION " + i + " ENDED");
        System.out.println();
    }

    return fields;
}
```

fields[] is an array of the type Field (basically has just one member (int id).

Comment: Um, how would anything get into the array? If it's not in the array already, then it can't be added because it's not a duplicate. I think you need to clarify your goal a little better.

Comment: What is this code here... your attempt?  It doesn't seem to prevent new Field instances from being put in the array with a different value.  In fact, it seems to try to come up with distinct values for each item in the array!  You did a lot of searching, but did you try just thinking it through?

Comment: My idea was to generate a random number and put it into the first index of the array aswell as in another random index of the array which is empty. Afterwards the next index gets chosen and another random number is generated. This random number is put into the second index of the array (if empty) and in another random index aswell (if empty) and so on. I expected the array to fill up with only duplicate values by the end. Is something wrong with my idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're after correctly, I think you're probably making this a lot harder than it has to be.

It is much easier to iterate over your `fields` array *in order* and add two `Fields` of the same value each iteration, then shuffle the array. Something like the following code:

```
{
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i += 2)
        fields[i] = fields[i + 1] = new Field(r.nextInt(pool));

    shuffleFields(fields);

    return fields;
}
```

You can take your pick of shuffling algorithms. The [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is popular. E.g.:

```
void shuffleFields (Field[] fields)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = fields.length - 1; i >= 1; --i)
    {
        int j = r.nextInt(i + 1);
        Field t = fields[i];
        fields[i] = fields[j];
        fields[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a much better approach than mine. Thank you and everyone else for the help. :)

Comment: @birdog: I'm glad you appreciate the answer!